# Facebook app review being stalled?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am considering the possibilty that Facebook is stalling the app review for a Dating app. We have waited 5 weeks in review now which seems a long time!

We are asking for permissions that were revoked in May. So we have had all permissions. We need permission to use user_gender and user_events.

Has anyone experience with waiting this long or experience with being stalled?

Comment: Yes it is a known thing.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/faqs#faq_981925055227977: _“Due to changes to the review process and the high volume of submissions expected, it may take several weeks for submitted apps to complete review.”_

Comment: @CBroe i have read that but understood that nearly all users have gotten I through Iin one or two weeks. I does not make sense that a live app with a business behind has to be shut down because they revoke your licenses. It could kill a business.

Comment: @WizKid what is a known thing?

Comment: This is about better protecting users from shady developers who abuse their access to the data … that your business has to take a back seat in that regard, should be pretty obvious.

Comment: @CBroe You think because it is a dating app it is more shady use of their API? We need a lot of data but there is no shady use. It is just a search algorithm.

Comment: No, I meant review is about that.

Comment: It took nearly 2 months. Just for an update